# Singleton with a Listener versus Join

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I inherited this code from a previous developer (lol). I'm considering changing this to support a join instead of using a listener kind of callback.

My requirements:
1. I need to have the calling thread wait until the DoMath class thread has completed.
2. I need to prevent other threads from calling it.

This, in another thread (and class) - :

```
DoMath.getInstance().performMathCalc();
```

It doesn't wait or sleep of course when it calls this:

```
public class DoMath {
    protected math calc() {
    }

    public static DoMath getInstance() {
        if(_instance == null) {
            _instance = new DoMath();
        }

        return _instance;
    }

    // perform a synchronous math calc, and return a boolean indicating success or failure.
    public boolean performMathCalc() {
        MathEngine.setApplicationMode(MathEngine.AUTO);
        MathEngine.getInstance().StartMathCalc(MathEngine.DIVISION);
        return true;
    }

    // perform an async math calc, and call back the listener when done
    public void performMathCalc(final listener client) {
        Thread mathThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                boolean result = performMathCalc();
                client.mathFinished(result);
            }
        });
        mathThread.setDaemon(true);
        mathThread.start();
    }

    public static interface listener {
        public void mathFinished(boolean success);
    }

    protected static DoMath _instance;
}
```

So, is it better to just use the listener or implement a join in the calling class?

Comment: don't wait, sleep, join or otherwise block the main thread. ever.

Comment: @njzk2 Good advice if you change "ever" to "when performing an operation that is advertised as *asynchronous*" (which certainly applies in this case).

Comment: Please also note that the aysnc code has what is probably a bug. The listener won't be called back on the thread that invoked performMathCalc, but instead on the background thread.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to have the calling thread wait until the DoMath class thread has completed.

You already have this.  Note how there are *two* `performMathCalc` methods:

1. The first method takes no arguments and performs the calculation on the caller thread, then returns the result.  This fulfills your first requirement.
2. The second method is an *asynchronous wrapper* for the first; it allows the caller to kick off a calculation, then go off an do something else with the understanding that, at some point in the future, someone will be notified that the operation has completed.  This is useful functionality, so I would keep it.

I do see one issue with the asynchronous wrapper, however: the listener will not be notified in the event that the core `performMathCalc()` method throws an exception.  Consider using a `try/catch/finally` block to ensure the listener always gets notified, even if an error occurs.  You'll need to decide whether to add a second callback to your listener (e.g., `mathFailed`) or to simply call `mathFinished(false)` on errors.

> I need to prevent other threads from calling it.

We can accomplish this easily enough, and since the asynchronous version simply delegates to the synchronous version, we only need to lock down the synchronous version.  The simplest way would be to mark the method as `synchronized`, since your class only provides one logical function:

```
public synchronized boolean performMathCalc() {
    MathEngine.setApplicationMode(MathEngine.AUTO);
    MathEngine.getInstance().StartMathCalc(MathEngine.DIVISION);
    return true;
}
```

Alternatively, if you end up extending your `DoMath` class to perform other kinds of operations that are not mutually exclusive, you can synchronize on operation-specific locks.

That leaves us with your singleton accessor:

```
public static DoMath getInstance() {
    if (_instance == null) {
        _instance = new DoMath();
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

This conditional initialization is **not** thread-safe.  Your singleton is very simple and doesn't have any up-front initialization costs, so simply mark `_instance` as `final static` and initialize it in the declaration.

Comment: I've upvoted all three - because each had salient takeaways that I could use. I was wondering if this was thread safe, now I know it isn't.

I did not know that join more or less turned into uhhmmmm ios background processing (unpredictable without push). Thanks for that.

Going with callbacks on a final static instance. THANK YOU!!!

(Surprised there were no upvotes on this but in my mind, the upvote were your answers. Thanks again!)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to pause your thread until the other one as finished? You should never, ever block the main thread.

```
The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,

t.join();
causes the current thread to pause execution until t's thread terminates. Overloads of join allow the programmer to specify a waiting period. However, as with sleep, join is dependent on the OS for timing, so you should not assume that join will wait exactly as long as you specify.
```

(from java docs)

Also, does performMatchCalc() needs to be public ?

Now, at first glance that code actually looks correct, but, you can still prevent someone from starting another calculation. Perhaps with something similar of this :

```
    public class DoMath {
        private Thread mathThread;

        protected math calc() {
        }

        public static DoMath getInstance() {
            if(_instance == null) {
                _instance = new DoMath();
            }

            return _instance;
        }

        // perform a synchronous math calc, and return a boolean indicating success or failure.
        public boolean performMathCalc() {
            if(null != mathThread && mathThread.isAlive())
                 return false;

            MathEngine.setApplicationMode(MathEngine.AUTO);
            MathEngine.getInstance().StartMathCalc(MathEngine.DIVISION);
            return true;
        }

        // perform an async math calc, and call back the listener when done
        public void performMathCalc(final listener client) {
           //re-start calculation? if so
           if(null != mathThread && mathThread.isAlive()) {
                 matchThread.interrupt();
                 matchThread = null;
            }


            mathThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    boolean result = performMathCalc();
                    client.mathFinished(result);
                }
            });
            mathThread.setDaemon(true);
            mathThread.start();
        }

      public static interface listener {
            public void mathFinished(boolean success);
        }

        protected static DoMath _instance;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do note that this:

```
public static DoMath getInstance() {
    if(_instance == null) {
        _instance = new DoMath();
    }

    return _instance;
}
```

is not thread-safe.  To ensure that your class really is a Singleton (relative to its ClassLoader) you must either synchronize that method or initialize the `_instance` member in its declaration.  Either way, `_instance` must be `private` or `final` or both.

As for your actual requirements,

(1) it seems you want to either change an asynchronous call into a synchronous one, or to put a synchronous wrapper around it.  You can do the latter via the existing listener interface, which would preserve the ability to perform asynchronous jobs.  If you don't want that then instead of joining, skip launching a new thread at all: just run the computation in the current thread.

(2) How you might prevent multiple threads from running calculations at the same time depends in part on how you address issue (1).  If you make everything synchronous then you can just make `DoMath.performMathCalc()` a synchronized method.  If you retain the asynchronous computation option then you could look to package java.util.concurrent.locks for classes that can help you.